# Unit vector perpendicular to another unit vector such that the z component is the largest

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I find a unit vector $\vec a = (a_x, a_y, a_z)$ perpendicular to a unit vector $\vec b = (b_x, b_y, b_z)$ such that $a_z$ is the largest possible?

The condition that $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are perpendicular can be expressed as: $\vec a \cdot \vec b = 0$.

The condition that $\vec a$ is a unit vector can be expressed as: $\vec a \cdot \vec a = 1$.

However, how can we express that $a_z$ is the largest possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know how to express two of the three equations that I need to determine $\vec a$, I don't find the way to express the condition that $a_z$ should be the largest possible.

Comment: The largest possible $a_z$ is actually a really nice formula that only involves $b_x$ and $b_y$. If you were to update your post to write all your effort I would write a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG consider $b_z > 0$. All possible vectors $\vec{a}$ lie on the circle which is the intersection of the plane $\vec{b}\cdot\vec{r} = 0$ and the sphere $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r} = 1$. The largest possible $a_z$ occurs when circle is at its closest approach to the $z$ axis, or in other words where $a_x^2+a_y^2$ is at its minimum. By simple vector geometry, we want the projection of this vector onto the $z$ axis. Since $\vec{b}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{a}$, this length is equivalent to the projection of $\vec{b}$ onto the $xy$ plane:

$$a_z = |\vec{b}|\cos\theta = \frac{\vec{b}\cdot(b_x,b_y,0)}{|(b_x,b_y,0)|} = \sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2}$$

Also from simple geometry, we know that $(a_x,a_y,0)$ would have to point in the $k\cdot(-b_x,-b_y,0)$ direction. The equation $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = 0$ leads us to

$$-kb_x^2 - kb_y^2 +b_z\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2} = 0 \implies k = \frac{b_z}{\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2}}$$

Therefore the vector we want is

$$\vec{a} = \frac{(-b_xb_z,-b_yb_z,b_x^2+b_y^2)}{\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2}}$$

Comment: Can also be obtained from $\vec{a}_{max\phantom{.}a_{z}}=\frac{\vec{b}\times\hat{k}}{\left\|\vec{b}\times\hat{k}\right\|} \times \vec{b}$

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the given solution, all possible vectors $\vec{a}$ lie on the circle which is the intersection of

- the plane $b_x x+b_yy+b_zz = 0$
- and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

therefore the maximum $z$ is attained at the point of intersecion with the plane containing $\vec b$ and the $z$ axis that has normal

$$\vec n=\vec b \times \hat z = (b_x, b_y, b_z) \times (0,0,1)=(b_y,-b_x,0) $$

the direction vector for the line intersection of the two planes is

$$\vec d= \vec n \times \vec b=(-b_xb_z,-b_yb_z,b_x^2+b_y^2)$$

and the intersecion of the line $t\vec d$ with the sphere leads to

$$t=\frac1{\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2}}$$

which leads to the solution

> $$\vec{a} = \frac{(-b_xb_z,-b_yb_z,b_x^2+b_y^2)}{\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2}}$$